# Interference of RF currents with a combiner

Tags: rf, interference, waveguide

I am trying to understand what happens to 2 RF currents flowing in separate planar waveguides (such as microstrip lines), when combined with a power combiner.

More specifically, will they interfere, considering they have identical frequencies and a fixed phase difference (as in optics)?

Comment: Please show the circuit of the power combiner, all series and parallel line terminations and, draw the microstrips as t-lines etc.. This is an EE site and, nearly always, a circuit diagram is best understood. You might also consider using a simulator to get your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by 'interfere'.

Assuming the microstrip lines and power combiner are linear, the signals will superpose. That is, the response of the circuit to both inputs together will be the sum of the responses to either input individually. If at a given point in space and time, the response to one would have been 1 A, and to the other would have been -1 A, the total response at that point would be zero current.

That is sort of the optical meaning of interference, two wave trains can add up to zero in certain circumstances.

It's not really the electrical meaning of interference, as if all the media are linear, the waves will carry on propagating through the medium, and can be separated again, they have not altered each other.

If there's a non-linear element somewhere in the path, a shunt diode for instance, now the two signals can mix, they will alter each other, and cause new frequency components to appear that were not in the original signals.